# How to grow the width of a div as the width screen decreases using Css?

Tags: css, responsive-design, media-queries

It does possible to adjust the width of a div as the width property of the browser is decreasing or increasing using pure Css?

I mean, if I have an element like this in a resolution:

```
div {
  width: 20%;
}
```

Then, I want to increase 1% the width of the div for every 10px that I decrease the width browser, it's possible  using just Css3?

Comment: The solution depends on how wide the window is when the div is at 20%.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Decreasing width as window is descreased is easy with CSS. **Increasing** width as window is decreasing is not.

Its possible to use a css only solution, but it will require a wild amount of `@media` queries:

[JS Fiddle (using larger percentage for example)](https://jsfiddle.net/80ypbxnc/)

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 400px) {
    div {
        width: 20%;
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 390px) {
    div {
        width: 21%;
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 380px) {
    div {
        width: 22%;
    }
}
```

etc...

CSS doesn't have the logic built in to calculate the width of a viewport AND apply styles based on it without manually doing it with a media query. A js solution would definitely be recommended.

Answer (score 1):

This also may help you a combination of the following code and use of calc() in CSS could help.

```
vw, vh
1vw = 1% of viewport width
1vh = 1% of viewport height
```

Let give it a try with your code.