# How to stop jump-changing margins of single column container

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, margin, viewport

I'm learning Bootstrap and I want to create simple div which is centered on the page.

[image: example of margins]

I really like that auto-margin of `container` class, but it seems to be jump-changing based on breakpoints when resizing window width.

I want to make margins getting smaller **smoothly** until they become 0 when window is small enough.

I have tried to explicitly set one column layout like this:

```
<div class="container border">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
            <p>container with some content</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

but the results are just the same and breakpoints all still used.

Comment: You're using Bootstrap's `.container` class, which defines max-widths for the itself at various breakpoints. Thus, the jumps as the window increases and decreases in available width.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Container-fluid vs .container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22262311/container-fluid-vs-container)

Comment: I think you're looking for this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39032122/how-to-grow-the-width-of-a-div-as-the-width-screen-decreases-using-css or this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36506878/continuously-adjust-element-size-as-screen-size-changes .. otherwise it looks like you need to add more media queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that you shouldn't use bootstrap containers, because they have fixed width on breakpoints. For smooth transition you should manually set width to you container in `%` or `vw` and margin in same units.

Comment: That did the trick, thank you. I thought that there is some way to do it with Bootstrap.

Comment: @MáraToner Yes, with `.container-fluid`.

Answer (score 1):

There are [two types of Bootstrap 4 Container](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/layout/overview/#containers): Fixed and Fluid.

> Choose from a responsive, fixed-width container (meaning its max-width changes at each breakpoint) or fluid-width (meaning it’s 100% wide all the time).

If you don't want the breakpoints, use the `container-fluid` class:

> Use `.container-fluid` for a full width container, spanning the entire width of the viewport.

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container-fluid border">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
            <p>container with some content</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

If you must, you can manually override Bootstrap's responsive `max-width` settings.

```css
.container.nobreakpoints {
  max-width:100%;
  width:800px; /* maximum width before margins appear */
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container border nobreakpoints">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
            <p>container with some content</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, can you please explain how `container-fluid` centers the div? It sets 0 margins even on desktop (1920px).

Comment: The same way as `.container`: `margin-left` and `margin-right` are set to "auto".